# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'qualitym_yaseen'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, laravel, shared-hosting

I have created an application in Laravel and completed it using a localhost MySQL database. When I was using a localhost XAMPP database, my application worked perfectly but, when I deployed my Laravel application on a newly purchased shared hosting and created a database in `cpanel` and created a user against that database with all privileges, it throws the error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'qualitym_yaseen'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

I have tried all possible solution but none worked.

This is my database connection in .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=qualitym_medicare
DB_USERNAME=qualitym_yaseen
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CPanel SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[1045\] Access denied for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64857385/cpanel-sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) From the Cpanel -> Remote MYSQL -> Copy Access hosts ip >
Add it to Access host -> add host

2) Once the IP is successfully added, paste it to the DB_HOST

Voila, your connection will work

Comment: this is just for demo i put the right password which i created against this user but i will return same error every time.

Comment: I checked this on 3 to 4 shared hosting and all will return this error access denied.

Comment: do you have access to ssh

Comment: ooh sorry, you need to update the host - DB_HOST="  ". https://www.hostinger.com/how-to/what-is-my-mysql-hostname Please check the article. This is for hostinger. Find for yours

Comment: i didn't try through ssh

Comment: In my case the hostname was wrong fire [select @@hostname] in the phpmyadmin and check your hostname first if it matched the given ip

Answer (score 0):

Just need update your params in .env file by something like;

```
DB_HOST= mysql.hostinger.com    
DB_DATABASE=u7979345345_user    
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

that info provides u in Control Panel>MySQL Databases from menu

https://www.hostinger.com/how-to/what-is-my-mysql-hostname

Comment: where to write this GRANT commend in cpanel phpMyAdmin?

Comment: oh i see you must change on DB_HOST and use mysql.hostinger.com and the other params like user and pass

Comment: so i suppose to use "mysql.hostinger.com" as my DB_HOST?

Comment: when changing host name this error shown "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known"

Comment: Which shared hosting are you using ?. Also please paste in your DB_HOST

Comment: FYI To run GRANT you need to access the server. it needs to be pasted in once you connect to sql

Comment: I am using hosterpk shared hosting

Comment: I am clueless of this hosting provider. Only hope please share your CPAnel photgraph so I could help you in navigating the option or you could raise a support ticket asking for the hostname

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198600/discussion-between-mightyteja-and-muhammad-yaseen).

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL Workbench to easily change the permissions.
Under Server -> User and Privileges.
Make host as % for username from which you want to access.

Comment: what does this % means?

Comment: % will allow the server to be accessed by any host name.

Comment: is it possible to make this  change through cpanel?

Comment: i also cannot create connection from Mysql workbench

Comment: you need to know the hostname for the Mysql workbench to connect. As first step connect your local machine.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-server-remotely-with-mysql-workbench

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question, the password has to be in quotes -> 'password' that solutions me in hostinger

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is incorrect. Passwords do not need to be in quotes, unless yu've gt space or # inside of the password. The .env files get parsed as strings regardless, but # means comment etc, hence, there are cases where quotes must be used, but in general - no.