# CPanel SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, laravel, hosting, cpanel, access-denied

I'm a fresher in Cpanel laravel hosting. I'm facing a specific problem  **SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'mbaam_trodian'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = phar@gmail.com limit 1)** and can't found any solution for 3 days.

Localhost:
[localhost setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsuXh.png)

database user:

[database user settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F2aw.png)

.env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mbaam_smart_hospital
DB_USERNAME=mbaam_trodian
DB_PASSWORD=*************
```

Answer (score 4):

Try and removed all special characters from database password and replace with only alphabet or alphanumeric. for instance, DB_PASSWORD= mbamTrod0105

Answer (score 2):

1. make database user in your cpanel
2. add newly created user into your .env file
3. clear cache `php artisan cache:clear` and then `php artisan config:cache` or you can delete the files into bootstrap/cache folder then your laravel project work fine

Comment: `DB_USERNAME=mbaam_trodian` where 'mbaam_trodian' is created by Cpanel             |      I also deleted all files as you said... but all in vain!

Comment: make another user for your database and then try with it

Comment: Sorry, brother... Nothing happens! One thing I want to confirm, which password should I use in creating a database user? my created password or generate a password???                ->   [Suggestion Plz](https://snipboard.io/uLjHVx.jpg)

Comment: tameemahmad shahzad thanks after struggling a lot your suggestion helps and save my day after deleting the bootstrap/cache

Answer (score 0):

mine worked after I created new user and assigned to the db.